# Using DocBlocks on PHP, Should I use @throws when I do not handle errors with execpetion?

Tags: php, comments, docblocks

I have a class for handling errors, and it is not using the `try-throw-catch` mechanism.

When I am commenting code that uses that class, should I use the the `@throws` tag even though I do not actually throwing anything?

**EDIT (try to make my question more clear):**

My question is if the `@throws` tags means that an error could occure when using the code and I am handling it in some way, or it means that an error could occure and I am handling it by using the `throw` keyword specifically?

Comment: comments are for increasing clarity. dont put @throw if its not possible to throw something.

Comment: Why don't you write it in an answer? :)

Comment: Because your question is not clear. Try to make it clear.

Comment: @Ali, done! Thanks. Could you now help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [the documentation](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/throws.html), I realize that this is not exactly spelled out.

The documentation on `@throws` suggests that if the `throw` keyword is present at all inside the block of code, then it should be documented for each type of exception that could be thrown regardless of whether or not you're handling it or not.

So if you have

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handled!
}
```

put a `@throws` entry in the docblock.

Answer (score 1):

Putting annotation @throws marked this method as insecure. The client should be prepared to handle this exception when calling this method.